TypeORM - Third relation table
The goal is simple. I have a table created by my self-hosted Strapi CMS, that I connect to with my NestJS backend. With this approach I want to keep working in the same Database, without making additional API calls to Strapi. The structure of the tables of interest looks like this:
@Entity({ name: 'posts' })
export class PostEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  ???
  category!: CategoryEntity;
}

@Entity({ name: 'categories' })
export class CategoryEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  ???
  posts!: PostEntity[];
}

@Entity('posts_category_links')
export class PostCategoryLinkEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column({ name: 'post_order' })
  postOrder!: number

  ???
  categoryId!: number;

  ???
  postId!: number;
}

The third table holds the IDs of the two Entities.
Conditions:

DB synchronize is set to false, Strapi might break if tables are modifified outside of it

Goals:

Following code should return all Posts with the CategoryEntity in the category key:
this.postsRepository.find({relations: ['category']})



Try this:


@Entity({ name: 'posts' })
export class PostEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @OneToOne(() => CategoryEntity, (item) => item.Category, { })
  category!: CategoryEntity;
}

@Entity({ name: 'categories' })
export class CategoryEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @OneToMany(() => PostEntity, (item) => item.Post)
  posts!: PostEntity[];
}

@Entity('posts_category_links')
export class PostCategoryLinkEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column({ name: 'post_order' })
  postOrder!: number

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  categoryId!: number;
  
  @OneToOne(() => CategoryEntity, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "categoryId", foreignKeyConstraintName: "category_fk" })
  Category: CategoryEntity;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  postId!: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => PostEntity, (post) => post.id, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "postId", foreignKeyConstraintName: "post_fk" })
  Post: PostEntity;
}



However,it maybe you need to apply a relation OneToMany with category!: CategoryEntity[];
